# CSS media queries - what minimum width should I take into account?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, viewport

I'm practicing with some responsive design basics and one question that a lot of tutorials don't answer explicitly is what minimum width to take into account when targeting mobile devices.

What I've seen most so far is `@media only screen and (max-width:480px){...}` for smartphones and then `@media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:768px){...}` for tablets. And so on.

I think the smallest screens that are used on a (reasonably) regular basis are 320px by 480px. However, the 320px width does not have to be taken into account due to the option of using landscape orientation. Right?

In other words, is it reasonable to assume that I'll **always have at least 480px of width** for a design? How do others handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Exact and ideal answer would be 320px.

Comment: Does that refer to a 480px by 320px viewport? If so, why not 480px instead of 320px?

Comment: @RubenGeert Because you can't asume the user will always use his device in landscape orientation.

Comment: Anything lower than 320px would ruin your design, so ideally, 320 is advisable. and Agreed with @user3008011

Comment: Sure. But if they don't, they probably will as soon as they view your site that's been designed for 480px width, right?

Comment: That is my point @RubenGeert, minimum width should be 320 and not 480, as that is not the right width that should be taken into account.

Comment: Most users would probably assume your site is broken or not optimized for web and move on. Not tilt their screen to see if it is optimized for a landscape orientation. But that would be more of a UX question.

http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Then do you use something like `max-width:320px` to target these cases? If so, then what do you target with the second media query? Something like 321px - 768px? I hope it's OK to ask that as I'm getting a bit more curious now.

Comment: Just this `@media screen and (min-width : 320px) {}` or `@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) {}` - @RubenGeert

Comment: @NathanLee: I see. Thanks for the answers, they're clear and helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It somehow depends upon your website's layout and design. The more you have complex layout and design you have to take a minimum width. In most cases your CSS code may be a reason to set minimum width media queries.

Comment: This seems to be a pretty vague answer.